# Using inner join with more than one condition

Tags: javascript, sql, knex.js

I have the following SQL:

```
select table2.employee_id as manager_id, table1.employee_id as employee_id, table3.has_day_off
from "company".employee as table1
inner join "company".employee table2 on (table1.manager_id = table2.id)
inner join "company".employee_details table3 on (table3.employee_id = table1.employee_id and table3.manager_id = table2.employee_id and table3.branch_type = '<type>')
where table1.employee_code = '<employee code'
```

where i'll return employeeId, managerId and "bool" dayOff from given employeeCode and branchType.
I tried a good amount of approaches to transfer this logic to Knex, inside a typescript application, but couldn't get to work.

Can anyone suggest an approach for this innerJoin with three variables?

Comment: 3rd example in http://knexjs.org/#Builder-innerJoin

Answer (score 0):

See Mikael's comment. I'll just make it explicit with an example:

```
knex
  .withSchema('company')
  .select(
    't2.employee_id as manager_id',
    't1.employee_id as employee_id',
    't3.has_day_off'
  )
  .from('employee t1')
  .innerJoin('employee t2', 't1.manager_id', 't2.id')
  .innerJoin('employee_details t3', function () {
    this.on('t3.employee_id', '=', 't1.employee_id')
      .andOn('t3.manager_id', '=', 't2.employee_id')
      .andOn('t3.branch_type', '=', '<type>')
  })
```

Not tested of course, but that's the general idea.